# How to create a table that I can add or remove columns from

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I need to produce a table similar to:

[image]

What we see is the left column containing the data point headers, and each column after contains the actual data.

I'd like to treat each column (other than the first one) as an optional column. The user can add or remove the columns based on funds they select. If they've selected only 1 fund, only the first 2 columns are visible, the rest of the spaces are blank. Each subsequent fund selection adds a new column to the table, up to a max of 5.

I'm wondering what is the best way to implement this? I'm thinking each column is an independent table of a fixed width that I can add to a container which can align them side by side. Will I have difficulty getting the 6 tables to line up side by side?

Is there a better way for me to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have invididual tables, or you could assign each column a class which would then allow you to add or remove all elements that have that class using Javascript.

For example:

```
<table>
<tr><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td><td class="col3"></tr>
<tr><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td><td class="col3"></tr>
</table>
```

You could then use Javascript to show/hide elements (via CSS) with the relevant class based on actions of the user. Depending on how big your table is, that could work.

Nice use of Comic Sans by the way!